# Correlation between revision time and exam performance

Tags: mathematical-statistics, correlation, pearson-r, spearman-rho

Assume that a student needs to do multiple exams $E_i (i=1,2...)$ across various subjects (e.g., math, physics, English, etc). 
For each exam $E_i$, I have the corresponding revision time of the student $R_i$ (days) and his exam performance $P_i$.

I want to investigate the effect of the revision time on the exam performance. I was thinking of computing the correlation between two lists $\{R_i\}$ and $\{P_i\}$. However, each exam has a specific subject, number of problems, grading method, and grading scale. For example,

- Exam $E_1$ is a math exam that has a grade scale of 0-100 points. There are 3 problems, namely, problem 1 (20 points), problem 2 (30 points), problem 3 (50 points). Each problem has some questions and the student might have partial credit for each question.
- Exam $E_2$ is a programming exam that has a grade scale of 0-5 points. There are 5 problems each might have some sub-tasks. For each problem, credit is given if and only if the student solved all the subtasks exactly (no partial credit). So, a grade $P_2 = 4/5$ means that the student solved exactly all the subtasks in 4 problems.
- etc.

I was wondering what is the best measure of the correlation between two lists $\{R_i\}$ and $\{P_i\}$? I am not sure if the Pearson or Spearman correlation coefficient is valid in this case.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: Such data cannot inform you about the effects of revision time on performance.  To appreciate why not, consider that it is possible for increased time to be associated with *decreased* performance, despite having a positive effect on performance, because those who need more time are those who are struggling with the material in the first place. You need to conduct a study in which you can measure student performance both after and *before* they begin their review.

Comment: The best way to tackle such problems is by normalizing your data (eg using z-scores). After that you should calculate the final grades by hand.

Comment: @whuber: Thanks for your answer. There is only one student in this case, so increasing the revision time for an exam would likely result in increased performance.

Comment: @M.Cris: Thanks! Even if I normalize all the exam scores on the same scale (e.g., 0-100), they are fundamentally computed on different exams in different ways. So I am still not sure if it is okay to use a measure like Spearman correlation coefficient, any thoughts?

Comment: Seems like there is no other way. Should you normalize the grades they will be relatable with each other and you could use pearson for the correlation even if they are calculated differently. There should be a problem if the student studies between the exams. For example a subject has 2 tests and they are being held a week apart. The student would study between them so they should be taken as different subjects (because they would be different exams).

Comment: @M.Cris: Thanks, Mr. Cris, do you know any material that mentions that we can use Pearson correlation coefficient when the values of a variable are calculated differently, similar to the above case?